# Uploading Files to AWS S3 Bucket Folder in Python Causes Regex Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an AWS S3 bucket called `task-details` and a folder called `archive` so the S3 URI is `s3://task-details/archive/` & ARN of `arn:aws:s3:::task-details/archive/`. I'm trying to use the `upload_file` method from Python's boto3 package to upload a CSV file to a folder within the S3 bucket.

Below is the method I am using to try and upload data to the folder but I keep getting a regex error which makes me think that I can't upload data to a specific folder in a bucket. Does anyone know how to do this?

Method:

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

My Code (I've also tried `bucket = s3://task-details/archive/` and `bucket = task-details/archive/`):

```
upload_file(
    file_name = filepath, 
    bucket = "arn:aws:s3:::task-details/archive/", 
    object_name = object_name
)
```

The Error:

```
Invalid bucket name "arn:aws:s3:::task-details/archive/": Bucket name must match the regex 
"^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API call wants the bucket name or ARN. Your bucket name is `task-details` and your bucket ARN is `arn:aws:s3:::task-details`.

You use the Key parameter when calling [upload_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) to specify the object's key, for example `archive/cats/persian.png`. Note that the S3 object key is not simply the object/file name but also includes the prefix/folder.

Comment: Right, but I want the file uploaded to a folder in the bucket, not to the top level of the bucket.

Comment: That's called a prefix and it's part of the object's key, not part of the bucket name.

Comment: @jarmod I have entered the bucket ARN in same format you suggest, and object key with path like your example, but still get the `invalid bucket name...` regex error:
invoke like:
upload_file("filename.yaml", "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name", "config/path/to/filename.yaml")

Comment: @208_man does your bucket already exist and does the bucket name actually comply with the regex? If yes to both, then maybe you could share your bucket name here with some minor obfuscation.

Comment: @jarmod. Yes the bucket already exists.  Replacing "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name" with "bucket-name" overcame the error.

Comment: Interesting that the current boto3 docs say it’s the bucket name but the error message in the original post above indicated that it could be an ARN. Personally I always use bucket name and maybe the error message above is a red herring. Certainly it seems that ARN is not supported.

Comment: Ok now that makes sense.  I couldn't get the ARN to pass the provided regex anyway.  What still boggles me is how this script knows what the account number is.

Comment: Bucket names are globally unique so you can infer the AWS account from the bucket name. Also, you’re supplying AWS credentials on the API call from which the AWS account associated with the credentials can be inferred.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I needed to add the folder path as part of the `object_name` instead of the `bucket`.

Fixed Code:

```
upload_file(
    file_name = filepath, 
    bucket = "arn:aws:s3:::task-details", 
    object_name = "archive/" + object_name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the other answers didn't resolve the error.  I had to change my bucket name from the arn ("arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name") to the bucket name alone ("bucket-name").

Adding a potentially helpful explanation from @jarmod:

Interesting that the current boto3 docs say it’s the bucket name but the error message in the original post above indicated that it could be an ARN. Personally I always use bucket name and maybe the error message above is a red herring. Certainly it seems that ARN is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to upload the contents of a zip file. Also I wanted to upload to a folder inside the bucket. So this is my working solution.

```
s3.upload_fileobj(
       Bucket='user-data',
       Key='my_extracted-files/' + file_name, # file_name is the name of file
       Fileobj=zop # This is a file obj
      )
```

My guess is the naming format of **bucket** and **key** params is the same for method: upload_file too

**Note**: Don't forget to add Put permissions in your policy